# Delay when adding lines to a UIBezierPath in CAShapeLayer

Tags: ios, swift, uibezierpath, cashapelayer

I am trying to implement functionality to allow a user to draw in a UIImageView. My current code is as follows:

```
class DrawImageView: UIImageView {

    // MARK: - Properties

    private var lastPoint = CGPoint.zero
    private var lineColor = UIColor.black
    private var lineWidth: CGFloat = 10.0
    private var opacity: CGFloat = 1.0
    private var path: UIBezierPath?
    private var swiped = false
    private var tempShapeLayer: CAShapeLayer?

    // MARK: - Initializers

    override init(image: UIImage?) {
        super.init(image: image)

        isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        clipsToBounds = true
    }

    @available(*, unavailable)
    private init() {
        fatalError("init() has not been implemented")
    }

    @available(*, unavailable)
    private override init(frame: CGRect) {
        fatalError("init(frame:) has not been implemented")
    }

    @available(*, unavailable)
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

}

// MARK: - Draw Methods

extension DrawImageView {

    private func drawLine(from fromPoint: CGPoint, to toPoint: CGPoint) {
        guard let tempShapeLayer = tempShapeLayer,
              let cgPath = tempShapeLayer.path
        else { return }

        let path = UIBezierPath(cgPath: cgPath)
        path.move(to: fromPoint)
        path.addLine(to: toPoint)

        tempShapeLayer.path = path.cgPath

        setNeedsDisplay()
    }

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        guard let touch = touches.first else { return }

        swiped = false
        lastPoint = touch.location(in: self)

        let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        shapeLayer.lineCap = .round
        shapeLayer.path = path?.cgPath
        shapeLayer.strokeColor = lineColor.cgColor
        shapeLayer.lineWidth = lineWidth
        shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        shapeLayer.frame = bounds

        let path = UIBezierPath()
        shapeLayer.path = path.cgPath

        layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
        shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.red.cgColor

        tempShapeLayer = shapeLayer
    }

    override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        guard let touch = touches.first else { return }

        swiped = true
        let currentPoint = touch.location(in: self)
        drawLine(from: lastPoint, to: currentPoint)
        lastPoint = currentPoint
    }

    override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        if !swiped {
            // Draw a single point
            drawLine(from: lastPoint, to: lastPoint)
        }
    }

}
```

This image view is embedded inside a scroll view:

```
class ZoomImageVC: UIViewController {

    // MARK: - Properties

    private let bag = DisposeBag()

    // MARK: - Views

    private let scrollView = UIScrollView()
    // Important this is init with image immediately
    private let backgroundImageView = DrawImageView(image: UIImage(named: "test.jpg"))


    // MARK: - View Lifecycle

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        setupViews()
    }

    override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()

        // This will update on rotate too
        updateMinZoomScaleForSize(view.bounds.size)
    }

    // MARK: - Setup

    private func setupViews() {
        view.backgroundColor = .white

        scrollView.delegate = self
        view.addSubview(scrollView)
        scrollView.snp.makeConstraints {
            $0.edges.equalToSuperview()
        }

        scrollView.rx.didZoom
            .subscribe(with: self, onNext: { `self`, _ in
                self.updateConstraintsForSize(self.view.bounds.size)
            })
            .disposed(by: bag)

        scrollView.addSubview(backgroundImageView)

        // This is DrawingImageView
        backgroundImageView.snp.makeConstraints {
            $0.edges.equalToSuperview()
        }
    }

    private func updateMinZoomScaleForSize(_ size: CGSize) {
        let widthScale = size.width / backgroundImageView.bounds.width
        let heightScale = size.height / backgroundImageView.bounds.height
        let minScale = min(widthScale, heightScale)

        scrollView.minimumZoomScale = minScale
        scrollView.zoomScale = minScale
    }

    private func updateConstraintsForSize(_ size: CGSize) {
        let yOffset = max(0, (size.height - backgroundImageView.frame.height) / 2.0)
        let xOffset = max(0, (size.width - backgroundImageView.frame.width) / 2.0)

        backgroundImageView.snp.remakeConstraints {
            $0.leading.trailing.equalToSuperview().offset(xOffset)
            $0.top.bottom.equalToSuperview().offset(yOffset)
        }

        view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }

}

// MARK: - UIScrollViewDelegate

extension ZoomImageVC: UIScrollViewDelegate {

    func viewForZooming(in scrollView: UIScrollView) -> UIView? {
        backgroundImageView
    }

}
```

The code works fine however there seems to be a small delay. For example if I start stroking a path there will be a slight delay until the path appears, continuing to draw the path seems to be smooth. I can scribble the path very fast and it keeps up. It's just the start of the drawing that lags.

If I just paint a single dot to the image view without dragging there also seems to be a small delay from me tapping to it appearing on the screen.

If I remove `DrawImageView` from the scroll view there seems to be no delay. Why would there be a delay when this is in a scroll view?

Comment: Did u try initialising the CAShapeLayer out side touchBegan?

Comment: @udi yes I tried initialising in the init method and just using a single CAShapeLayer. It didn't fix the problem

Comment: Have you tried to put displayIfNeeded() after setNeedsDisplay() flag? It should start redrawing right in the place you call it and might fix your delay

Comment: @E.Shishko yes tried this, no different.

Answer (score 1):

Ran your code and not sure what "delay" you're seeing.

However, you're doing a few things that you don't need to do...

You can use a single path and add lines as the touch moves... no need to moveTo / addLineTo every time.

Also, if you want the initial "dot" to show up as soon as the touch begins, you can moveTo / addLineTo the touch point on `touchesBegan`.

Here's your class, edited to (hopefully) get rid of the delay you're experiencing:

```
class DrawImageView: UIImageView {
    
    // MARK: - Properties
    
    private var lineColor = UIColor.black
    private var lineWidth: CGFloat = 10.0
    private var opacity: CGFloat = 1.0

    // let's make these non-optional
    private var drawingPath: UIBezierPath!
    private var drawingShapeLayer: CAShapeLayer!
    
    // MARK: - Initializers
    
    override init(image: UIImage?) {
        super.init(image: image)
        
        isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        clipsToBounds = true
    }
    
    @available(*, unavailable)
    private init() {
        fatalError("init() has not been implemented")
    }
    
    @available(*, unavailable)
    private override init(frame: CGRect) {
        fatalError("init(frame:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    @available(*, unavailable)
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
}

/// MARK: - Draw Methods

extension DrawImageView {
    
    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        guard let touch = touches.first else { return }
        
        let thisPoint = touch.location(in: self)

        // create new shape layer
        drawingShapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        drawingShapeLayer.lineCap = .round
        drawingShapeLayer.strokeColor = lineColor.cgColor
        drawingShapeLayer.lineWidth = lineWidth
        drawingShapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        drawingShapeLayer.frame = bounds
        
        // create new path
        drawingPath = UIBezierPath()
        // move to touch point
        drawingPath.move(to: thisPoint)
        // if we want the line (an initial "dot")
        //  to show up immediately
        //  add line to same touch point
        drawingPath.addLine(to: thisPoint)
        // assign the shape layer path
        drawingShapeLayer.path = drawingPath.cgPath
        
        // add the layer
        layer.addSublayer(drawingShapeLayer)
    }
    
    override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        guard let touch = touches.first else { return }
        
        let thisPoint = touch.location(in: self)
        // add line to existing path
        drawingPath.addLine(to: thisPoint)
        // update path of shape layer
        drawingShapeLayer.path = drawingPath.cgPath
    }
    
    override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        // don't really need to do anything here
        //  unless you're taking some other action when
        //  touch ends
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer! Your code is definitely an improvement over mine.

I tried it and actually it performs about the same. However I didn't mention that this image view is embedded in a scroll view. I tried removing the image view from the scroll view and that fixed the delay issues. Any idea why the scroll view would cause a delay? I updated my question.

Comment: I found it! Strangely enough if I disable`isScrollEnabled`, this fixes the delay. Maybe there's a problem with the touch events clashing. This fixes the problem for my use case since the canvas won't be able to pan while painting is enabled.